# Problem with LayoutInflator to set TextView Android

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-inflate

Hey folks Im using two layouts, one embedded through an 'include' in the main layout file. 
I wish to set the TextView in the embedded one within the activity for the main xml. Here's what I've come up with so far......

Main xml: date_list_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@drawable/bgoption">

<include layout="@layout/cur"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Embedded xml: cur.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/currency"  
  android:textSize="14px"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:textColor="#d17375"
  ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then my Activity code sets the content to the main xml but tries to inflate the embedded one to set the text as follows......

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_list_layout);

View v  = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.cur,
            null);

    TextView currency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currency);
    currency.setText("test");
```

}

I'm not getting any errors but the TextView remains empty. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Thanks
A

Comment: Try to use the view directly as TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currency);(remove "View" reference v),it may help you,you can get the included layout information directly

Comment: Yep it does indeed, thanks for that.

Comment: As @riser pointed out: once you have `include`d cur.xml you no longer need to inflate manually. It is automatically inserted into the structure, so you can safely remove the additional `LayoutInflater` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setText directly in TextView. Without calling LayoutInflater in activity.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.date_list_layout);

 TextView currency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currency);
 currency.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just directly use the `TextView`:

```
 TextView currency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currency);
```

Once you have `include`d **cur.xml** you no longer need to inflate manually. It is automatically inserted into the structure, so you can safely remove the additional `LayoutInflater` call.